# am force-stop command error on Android 5.0

Tags: android

> am force-stop PACKAGE-NAME

doesnot work on my galaxy S5 with android 5.0 but does work on my galaxy win Jelly Bean 4.1.2

here is the screenshot anybody faced same error im using correct command but still error

> Error Type 2 Android.util.AndroidException : Can't Connect To Activity
>   Manager ; is the system running ?

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: any help or anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
am force-stop --user current c.c.c